# Android Chip Custom Height Or Padding - Chipgroup spacing

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, material-components, android-chips

Is there a way to change default material Chip vertical padding or height? From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/chip/Chip) I see there surely is a way to set the minimal height, but I would like to make chips "thinner", like in this design:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a very straightforward way to achieve what I want: all I needed to do was to set the `android:layout_height` attribute on the `ChipGroup` enclosing my chips.

I guess it makes sense that it's not possible to achieve that on a single chip... :>

Comment: If you just restrict the height with the "android:layout_height", it can cut the chip. The better way is to change the parameter "chipMinTouchTargetSize" to 0 as @Pramod Garg suggested

Answer (score 89):

In the 1.1.0-alpha* versions extra spacing is added for the chip. After a lot of hit and trial I managed to remove that spacing using:

```
app:chipMinTouchTargetSize="0dp"
```

Looking at the class file for Chip, it seems that it's related to Android's minimum touch target size, so consider that before changing this.

Comment: Thanks! This was so annoying and puzzling.

Comment: Additionally one can achieve this behavior by calling setEnsureMinTouchTargetSize(false) on the Chip programmatically.

Comment: It's incredible how Android creators can hide margin setting under such name. Thanks!

Comment: Many thanks! After searching much, finally, you solution worked.

Comment: UPDATE: just app:chipMinHeight="{size}" is required to change the size of the chip.

Comment: how to set chipMinTouchTargetSize programatically as my chip are dynamically created in the Kotlin Code

Comment: Thanks a lot. app:chipMinTouchTargetSize is not mentioned upfront anywhere.

Comment: It can be achieved also with app:ensureMinTouchTargetSize="false" which is imho better approach.

Comment: This is the answer. Thanks a lot friend

Answer (score 29):

Belows are the Chip Attributes for padding. Hopefully, It may help you

**Paddings**

```
app:chipStartPadding
app:iconStartPadding
app:iconEndPadding
app:textStartPadding
app:textEndPadding
app:closeIconStartPadding
app:closeIconEndPadding
app:chipEndPadding
```

Fore more info: [Click here](https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/)

Comment: Sorry, I probably wasn't too clear, I am looking for something in the lines of textBottomPadding and textTopPadding OR chipHeight :) or some dirty hack to achieve it.

Comment: It would be better to customize your own chip by the help of drawable.

Comment: yep, that's what I'll probably end up doing, just wanted to make sure I am not missing something first.

Comment: I found this third party library: http://code.hootsuite.com/making-nachos-a-material-chips-library-for-android/

Comment: If you want to make custom then have a look over this link: http://www.devexchanges.info/2017/01/android-material-design-component-chip.html

Answer (score 25):

In order to make a Chip thinner, you need to adjust two properties: chip height and text size.

```
<style name="ThinnerChip" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Action">
    <item name="chipCornerRadius">12dp</item>
    <item name="chipMinHeight">24dp</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/SmallerText</item>
</style>

<style name="SmallerText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small">
    <item name="android:textSize">11sp</item>
</style>
```

Then apply the style as ussually.

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
    style="@style/ThinnerChip"
    ...
    />
```

Answer (score 19):

This removed default vertical paddings for me:

```
app:ensureMinTouchTargetSize="false"
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use a custom style:

```
  <style name="MaterialComponents_Chip_Thin" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Entry">
    <item name="chipMinHeight">24dp</item>
    <item name="chipMinTouchTargetSize">24dp</item>
    <item name="chipIconSize">18dp</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body2_Thin</item>
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MaterialComponents.Chip_Thin</item>
  </style>
  <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MaterialComponents.Chip_Thin" parent="">
    <item name="cornerSize">12dp</item>
  </style>
  <style name="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body2_Thin" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body2">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
  </style>
```

And apply it with:

```
    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        style="@style/MaterialComponents_Chip_Thin"
        .../>
```

[image]

Comment: `chipMinTouchTargetSize` is what I was missing. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You have to set the height of your Chip to make it "thinner".
Check below code:

**build.gradle (app)**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
```

**ic_vector_android.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:pathData="M6,18c0,0.55 0.45,1 1,1h1v3.5c0,0.83 0.67,1.5 1.5,1.5s1.5,-0.67 1.5,-1.5L11,19h2v3.5c0,0.83 0.67,1.5 1.5,1.5s1.5,-0.67 1.5,-1.5L16,19h1c0.55,0 1,-0.45 1,-1L18,8L6,8v10zM3.5,8C2.67,8 2,8.67 2,9.5v7c0,0.83 0.67,1.5 1.5,1.5S5,17.33 5,16.5v-7C5,8.67 4.33,8 3.5,8zM20.5,8c-0.83,0 -1.5,0.67 -1.5,1.5v7c0,0.83 0.67,1.5 1.5,1.5s1.5,-0.67 1.5,-1.5v-7c0,-0.83 -0.67,-1.5 -1.5,-1.5zM15.53,2.16l1.3,-1.3c0.2,-0.2 0.2,-0.51 0,-0.71 -0.2,-0.2 -0.51,-0.2 -0.71,0l-1.48,1.48C13.85,1.23 12.95,1 12,1c-0.96,0 -1.86,0.23 -2.66,0.63L7.85,0.15c-0.2,-0.2 -0.51,-0.2 -0.71,0 -0.2,0.2 -0.2,0.51 0,0.71l1.31,1.31C6.97,3.26 6,5.01 6,7h12c0,-1.99 -0.97,-3.75 -2.47,-4.84zM10,5L9,5L9,4h1v1zM15,5h-1L14,4h1v1z"/>
</vector>
```

**your_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e3e3e3"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:chipSpacing="18dp">

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Entry"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:checkable="false"
            android:text="KRAKOW"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:textColor="#636161"
            app:chipCornerRadius="10dp"
            app:chipIcon="@drawable/ic_vector_android"
            app:chipIconSize="14dp"
            app:chipIconTint="#636161"
            app:chipStartPadding="8dp"
            app:chipStrokeColor="#636161"
            app:chipStrokeWidth="1dp"
            app:closeIconEnabled="false" />

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Entry"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:checkable="false"
            android:text="Today"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            app:chipBackgroundColor="#636161"
            app:chipCornerRadius="10dp"
            app:closeIconEnabled="false" />

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Entry"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:checkable="false"
            android:text="Tomorrow"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            app:chipBackgroundColor="#636161"
            app:chipCornerRadius="10dp"
            app:chipIcon="@drawable/ic_vector_android"
            app:chipIconSize="14dp"
            app:chipStartPadding="8dp"
            app:closeIconEnabled="false" />
    </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

To get the thinner Chip I have to set the following properties:

```
android:layout_height="20dp" // Thinner Height
app:chipIconSize="14dp"      // Smaller icon size
app:chipStartPadding="8dp"   // Add padding to start of icon
app:chipCornerRadius="10dp"  // Set Corner radius
```

**Preview**
[image]

Comment: Hi Viraj, How to set the layout height for a dynamic chip programmatically!!?

Comment: @adi Instead of creating chip programmatically, add an inflated layout to the chip group. That way you have full control of height via xml layout. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58247341/1135631

Answer (score 2):

Use setEnsureMinTouchTargetSize(false) to ensure the spacing is minimal.

```
Chip chip = new Chip(getContext());
    chip.setId(selectedWordGroup.id);
    chip.setText(selectedWordGroup.getName());
    chip.setTag(i);
    chip.setCheckable(true);
    chip.setCheckedIconVisible(false);
    chip.setChecked((mFlashcardSetupActivity.allWordGroups.get(i).getSelected()));
    chip.setClickable(true);
    chip.setFocusable(true);
    chip.setEnsureMinTouchTargetSize(false);
    chip.setChipDrawable(ChipDrawable.createFromAttributes(getContext(), null, 0, R.style.CustomChipChoice));

    chip.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean selected) {
        }
    });
    mChipGroupGroups.addView(chip);




<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
                    android:id="@+id/chip_group_groups"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    card_view:chipSpacing="4dp"
                >
```

Comment: in my case, chip.setEnsureMinTouchTargetSize(false); is solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**using java code :**

```
int paddingDp = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10,
                getResources().getDisplayMetrics()); 

        mChip.setPadding(paddingDp, 0, paddingDp, 0);
```

output :

[image: chips.png]

Answer (score 0):

```
 //need or other way put parent ChipGroup LinearLayout and set h*W  
  //and  also width and height

 <com.google.android.material.chip.Chipandroid 
    android:paddingLeft="10dp" 
    android:paddingRight="10dp" 
    android:layout_width="10dp" 
    android:layout_height="10dp" 
    app:mcv_textColor="@color/white" />
```

Comment: this will break on different font size

Comment: @rishabh deep Singh u need to set size in dimantion different size layout xdpi,mdpi,xxdpi

Answer (score 0):

If you add multiline Chip dynamically to ChipGroup until it expand to multiple rows, there is zero margin vertical margin.
Set app:chipSpacingVertical on ChipGroup to enable margin spacing.

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
    android:id="@+id/mainTagChipGroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:chipSpacingVertical="4dp"
    />
```

NOTE: You can set app:chipSpacingHorizontal or app:chipSpacing as well.
NOTE: Strangely, default margin for static Chip defined in xml vs dynamic Chip added programatically is different. I am using com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha04.
NOTE: Setting layoutParams on Chip doesn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

`app:chipStartPadding="@dimen/_10sdp"`

Answer (score 0):

use app:chipMinHeight="" property.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me

app:chipSpacingVertical="-14dp"