# Change Chip Widget style programmatically not working - Android

Tags: android, kotlin, material-components, material-components-android, android-chips

I'm doing a list with Chips. I want this chips can be selected, so, taking a look to https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/ I see I can have a "Choice Chip".

As I need to create and add dynamically I have to configure with specific colors, color ripplem, ...

So what I have to configure it is:

```
val chip = Chip(context, null, R.style.CustomChipChoice)
            chip.isClickable = true
            chip.isCheckable = true
            chip.isCheckedIconVisible=false
            chip.height = ScreenUtils.dpToPx(40)
            chip.chipCornerRadius = (ScreenUtils.dpToPx(20)).toFloat()
            chip.chipStrokeWidth = (ScreenUtils.dpToPx(2)).toFloat()
            chip.setTextAppearanceResource(R.style.ChipTextStyle)
            return chip
```

What I try with `R.style.CustomChipChoice` is:

**CustomChipChoice style**

```
<style name="CustomChipChoice" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice">
        <item name="chipBackgroundColor">@color/background_color_chip_state_list</item>
        <item name="chipStrokeColor">@color/background_color_chip_state_list</item>
        <item name="rippleColor">@color/topic_social_pressed</item>
</style>
```

**background_color_chip_state_list**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/topic_social_selected" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/topic_social_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/topic_unselected_background" />
</selector>
```

**stroke_color_chip_state_list**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/topic_social_pressed" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/grey_material2" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

As you can see, I make the chip, clickable and checkable (hiding the check icon I don't need).

But when I test it, the colors are not set. The chips just look as default colors (grey's scale)

Where can I apply or how, this custom style?

P.S:

I have done a fast test, to see if my CustomStyle was malformed/etc..

I added a view via xml and worked perfectly...

```
<android.support.design.chip.Chip
                android:id="@+id/test"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/CustomChipChoice"
                android:checkable="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                app:checkedIconVisible="false"
                android:text="Chip Test"/>
```

Answer (score 62):

You **can't use** the constructor `val chip = Chip(context, null, R.style.CustomChipChoice)` because the **3rd** parameter isn't the style but the attribute in the theme as `R.attr.chipStyle`.
The `Chip` hasn't a constructor with 4 parameters as other components because it extends `AppCompatCheckbox` which does not support a 4 parameter constructor.

However you can use something different.
**1st option**:

Just use a **xml layout** (`single_chip_layout.xml`) to define the single `Chip` with your **favorite style**:

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/CustomChipChoice"
    ...
/>
```

with

```
<style name="CustomChipChoice" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice">
...
</style>
```

Then instead of `val chip = Chip(context, null, R.style.CustomChipChoice)` use:

```
val chip = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_chip_layout, chipGroup, false) as Chip
```

In java:

```
Chip chip =
          (Chip) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.single_chip_layout, chipGroup, false);
```

**2nd option**:

Another option is to use the `setChipDrawable` method to override the `ChipDrawable` inside the `Chip`:

```
  Chip chip = new Chip(this);
  ChipDrawable chipDrawable = ChipDrawable.createFromAttributes(this,
      null,
      0,
      R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_Chip_Choice);
  chip.setChipDrawable(chipDrawable);
```

Comment: Option **one** works perfectly. With the **second** option, chip's selected text colors does not change as per defined style. While cross checking with source code, could find `chipDrawable.setShouldDrawText(false);` in `setChipDrawable` method defined in  `com.google.android.material.chip` .Not sure why textview was implemented this way, preventing editing programmatically.  Comment in source says `Defers to TextView to draw the text and ChipDrawable to render the rest (e.g. chip / check / close icons)`

Comment: @Sreehari if you also pass your custom style to chip.setTextAppearance method you can have the complete behaviour with the 2nd option of Gabriele Mariotti

Comment: Tried Option 2 by setting the same style to text appearance as suggested by @Irving Lop but doesn't seem to work for me. When the Chip is selected the text colour isn't changing as per the defined style.

Comment: I have followed Option 1, It works perfectly.

I have one query -> Can we set a Parcelized Object data on Chip, so that if the chip is checked then we can extract the required value from it.

for e.g. - model with id & name on-chip itself?

Comment: THIS IS SOLUTION FAR  BEST ON THE INTERNET. EVEN IN 2023

Answer (score 16):

In order to set the chip style in code you can try the following:

```
val chip = Chip(context)
val drawable = ChipDrawable.createFromAttributes(context, null, 0, R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_Chip_Choice)
chip.setChipDrawable(drawable)
```

Answer (score 11):

the `CustomChipChoice` is not a style it is just a reference to a style. therefore change `R.style.CustomChipChoice` to it : `R.attr.CustomChipChoice`

```
val newChip = Chip(context, null, R.attr.CustomChipChoice)
```

but before it you should add this `CustomChipChoice`in `values.xml` file in your project.
for this. if your project does not have the `values.xml` create it in `values` directory.

then add `CustomChipChoice` like this.

**values.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="CustomChipChoice" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

now in `styles.xml` add your style like this.

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        .
        .
        <item name="CustomChipChoice">@style/CustomChipChoiceStyle</item>
        .
        .
</style>
```

now that `CustomChipChoice` attr references to this style
and now you can create your custom style in `styles.xml` file.

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="CustomChipChoiceStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Action">
        .
        <item name="checkedIconVisible">false</item>
        <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
        <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
        <item name="chipBackgroundColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="chipIcon">@drawable/ic_filter</item>
        <item name="chipIconVisible">true</item>
        <item name="textStartPadding">0dp</item>
        <item name="textEndPadding">0dp</item>
        .
        .
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/ChipTextStyleAppearance</item>
</style>
```

if you want to change text appearance of chip. here is `ChipTextStyleAppearance`. you can add it like this.

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="ChipTextStyleAppearance">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/main_font</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">13dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

dont forget to add the `AppTheme` in `androidManifest.xml` on `application` or `activity` tags.

**androidManifest.xml**

```
<application
        .
        .
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<activity
            .
            .
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There's another very simple approach to this.

**styles.xml**

```xml
<style name="Widget.MyApp.Chip" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.MyApp.Chip</item>
    <item name="chipIconTint">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

**theme.xml**

```xml
<style name="Theme.MyApp.MyTheme" parent="Base.Theme.MyApp">
    <item name="chipStyle">@style/Widget.MyApp.Chip</item>
</style>
```

With this, all chips in activities that have the theme `Theme.MyApp.MyActivity` applied to it will follow this custom style whether the chip has been added through xml or programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

### Kotlin

xml

```
    <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
                android:id="@+id/chipGroup"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
</com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

Class

```
 data class Parametro(
       var idParametro: Long,
       var nombreParametro: String? )
```

Main

```
        listParametro.forEach { it->
                    val chip = Chip(context)
                    chip.id= it.idParametro.toInt()
                    chip.text= it.nombreParametro
                    chip.isClickable = true
                    chip.isCheckable = true
                    chip.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
                        Log.i("checkedChipIds","${buttonView.id} $isChecked")
                    }
                    mBinding.chipGroup.addView(chip)
                }
```

it works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Define Styles in themes.xml

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    ....
    <item name="chipStyle">@style/Widget.App.Chip</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.App.Chip" parent="Widget.Material3.Chip.Suggestion">
    <item name="chipIconTint">@color/black</item>
    <item name="chipBackgroundColor">@color/chip_bg_tint</item>
    <item name="chipStrokeWidth">0.5dp</item>
    <item name="chipMinHeight">32dp</item>
    <item name="closeIconVisible">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="chipStrokeColor">@color/stroke_tint</item>
    <item name="checkedIconVisible">false</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/chipTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="shapeAppearance">@style/ShapeAppearance.App.SmallComponent</item>
</style>

<style name="chipTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Material3.BodyMedium">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/poppins_regular</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/poppins_regular</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="ShapeAppearance.App.SmallComponent" parent="ShapeAppearance.Material3.SmallComponent">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">6dp</item>
</style>
```

Then Use this method to dynamically create Chips

```
val chip = createChip("Himalayas")

private fun createChip(textValue: String): Chip {
    return Chip(context).apply {
        id = ViewCompat.generateViewId()
        val drawable = ChipDrawable.createFromAttributes(context, null,
            0, R.style.Widget_App_Chip)
        setChipDrawable(drawable)
        setTextAppearance(R.style.chipTextAppearance)
        text = textValue
    }
}
```

And then add the newly created chip to any viewgroup. Eg:

```
myLinearLayout.addView(chip) OR

myChipGroup.addView(chip)
```

[Output of Dynamically added chips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I92gb.png)