# Unable to apply style to Android Material Component Chip programmatically

Tags: android, android-styles, material-components, material-components-android, android-chips

This is the screenshot of what I am working on.

[image]

There are two classes involved here. DraggableLayout and DraggableChip. Now, I want to change the style of the chip to `R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_Chip_Entry`

This is what the code looks like:

```
private void setupDraggableChipLayout() {
        DraggableLayout draggableLayout = this.findViewById(R.id.draggableLayout);

        androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_Chip_Entry);
        DraggableChip chip1 = new DraggableChip(contextWrapper, null, 0);
        chip1.setText("Chip1");
        chip1.enableCancelIcon(true);


        DraggableChip chip2 = new DraggableChip(this);
        chip2.setText("Chip2");



        DraggableChip chip3 = new DraggableChip(this);
        chip3.setText("Chip3");

        draggableLayout.addChip(chip1);
        draggableLayout.addChip(chip2);
        draggableLayout.addChip(chip3);

    }
```

I have tried using ContextWrapper but it does not work.

I have referred to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58247341/1117531). But how to do it without using a layout file?

Comment: I've updated the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53557863/change-chip-widget-style-programmatically-not-working-android/58247341#58247341). The only way to avoid the layout file is to use the `chip.setChipDrawable(chipDrawable)` method. In the Chip there isn't the 4th parameter to set the style in the constructor.

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59390473/1079842

Comment: 2nd option in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58247341/1117531) worked for me.