# Adding Chips into ChipGroup dynamically: border is not visible?

Tags: android-layout, android-chips

This is how I make a static ChipGroup

```
 <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
        android:id="@+id/chip_group_filter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/searchPromo"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        app:singleSelection="false">

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:id="@+id/chpFoodcourt"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Foodcourt"
            android:textColor="#0088BE"
            app:chipStrokeColor="#0088BE"
            app:chipStrokeWidth="1dp" />

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:id="@+id/chpParking"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Parking"
            android:textColor="#0088BE"
            app:chipStrokeColor="#0088BE"
            app:chipStrokeWidth="1dp" />

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:id="@+id/chpRestaurant"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Restaurant"
            android:textColor="#0088BE"
            app:chipStrokeColor="#0088BE"
            app:chipStrokeWidth="1dp" />

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:id="@+id/chpRetail"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Retail"
            android:textColor="#0088BE"
            app:chipStrokeColor="#0088BE"
            app:chipStrokeWidth="1dp" />

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:id="@+id/chpGame"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Game"
            android:textColor="#0088BE"
            app:chipStrokeColor="#0088BE"
            app:chipStrokeWidth="1dp" />

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:id="@+id/chpCafe"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cafe"
            android:textColor="#0088BE"
            app:chipStrokeColor="#0088BE"
            app:chipStrokeWidth="1dp" />

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:id="@+id/chpFashion"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Fashion"
            android:textColor="#0088BE"
            app:chipStrokeColor="#0088BE"
            app:chipStrokeWidth="1dp" />

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:id="@+id/chpHospital"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hospital"
            android:textColor="#0088BE"
            app:chipStrokeColor="#0088BE"
            app:chipStrokeWidth="1dp" />
    </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

[image]

Then, instead having hardcoded Chips, I want to fetch the fitch list from API, like this:

```
 val interestList = arguments?.getStringArrayList("INTEREST_LIST")

 interestList.forEach {
     val theChip = Chip(requireActivity())
     theChip.text = it.toString()
     theChip.isCheckable = true
     theChip.isClickable = true
     theChip.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0088BE"))
     //theChip.setTextAppearanceResource(R.style.Widget_Material3_Chip_Filter)

     chipGroupFilter.addView(theChip)
 }
```

And here's the result. The chip list is fetched correctly, except the rounded rectangle border isn't drawn.
[image]

Yes, the border only appears after it's clicked, though

[image]

How to make the rounder rectangle border always visible?

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a style in your XML but there is no style in the code you use to create the *Chips* programmatically. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58247341/6287910) for a way to pass along the style. I prefer the inflation method.